# "drop"/"drop off"

Tags: word-usage

> ...When the body of the gangster crashes onto the hood of his car. Pete screams terrified and hits the gas in panic. Desperate to **drop the body**, but instead it rolls into his windshield, making it impossible for him to see anything.

Questions:

Is **drop** correct?

Is **drop the body** correct? Or should it be one of these:

> drop off the body.
>
> drop the body off.
>
> drop the body off the car.

?

Comment: _Drop off_ suggests that he is delivering the body somewhere! I would suggest _be rid of_ or _lose_ rather than _drop_. NB _Desperate_ needs a subject - _He is desperate_.

Comment: The entire last sentence is very unclear because it doesn't seem to have a main phrase.  What is the main verb in it supposed to be?  It should be something like "He is desperate", as Kate says, or part of the last sentence, like "Pete screams terrified and hits the gas in panic COMMA desperate to drop the body, but..."